# ScrollView not scrolling to bottom in some devices while using Sliding Menu library

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am using [Sliding Menu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/master/library)   In this i have used `Scrollview` in sliding view, i have checked i haven't used any margin even not padding inside but still `ScrollView` not scrolling to bottom . While using same view inside normal `activity` it is working perfectly.

xml View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/carbon_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.quade.uxarmy.customview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/cvUserImage"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_64"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_64"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <carbon.widget.TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUserName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/size_05"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@color/carbon_black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_normal_18"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:carbon_fontPath="@string/font_regular" />

        <carbon.widget.TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCredits"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Credits"
            android:textColor="@color/carbon_black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_small"
            app:carbon_fontPath="@string/font_regular" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llProfile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                app:carbon_rippleColor="@color/gray_normal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile" />

                <carbon.widget.RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_12"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_12"
                    android:weightSum="1">

                    <carbon.widget.TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtProfile"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:text="@string/my_profile_"
                        android:textColor="@color/carbon_black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium"
                        app:carbon_fontPath="@string/font_regular" />


                    <com.quade.uxarmy.customview.CustomProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/pbProfileProgress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/txtProfile"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_05"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_05" />

                    <carbon.widget.TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtProgressPer"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@id/pbProfileProgress"
                        android:text="67% completed"
                        android:textColor="@color/carbon_black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_v_small"
                        app:carbon_fontPath="@string/font_regular" />

                </carbon.widget.RelativeLayout>

            </carbon.widget.LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_05"
                android:background="#99ADAFA4" />

            <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llHome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_10"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_10"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_10"
                app:carbon_rippleColor="@color/gray_normal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/home_icon" />

                <carbon.widget.TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                    android:text="Home"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/carbon_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium"
                    app:carbon_fontPath="@string/font_regular"
                    app:carbon_textAllCaps="false" />


            </carbon.widget.LinearLayout>

            <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llFeedback"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_10"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_10"
                app:carbon_rippleColor="@color/gray_normal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/feedback" />

                <carbon.widget.TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtFeedback"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                    android:text="Feedback"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/carbon_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium"
                    app:carbon_fontPath="@string/font_regular"
                    app:carbon_textAllCaps="false" />


            </carbon.widget.LinearLayout>

            <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llShare"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_10"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_10"
                app:carbon_rippleColor="@color/gray_normal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/share" />

                <carbon.widget.TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                    android:text="Share this app"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/carbon_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium"
                    app:carbon_fontPath="@string/font_regular"
                    app:carbon_textAllCaps="false" />


            </carbon.widget.LinearLayout>

            <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llRate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_10"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_10"
                app:carbon_rippleColor="@color/gray_normal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/rate" />

                <carbon.widget.TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                    android:text="Rate the app"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/carbon_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium"
                    app:carbon_fontPath="@string/font_regular"
                    app:carbon_textAllCaps="false" />


            </carbon.widget.LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_10"
                android:background="#99ADAFA4" />

            <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llAbout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_10"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_10"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_10"
                app:carbon_rippleColor="@color/gray_normal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/about" />

                <carbon.widget.TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                    android:text="About Us"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/carbon_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium"
                    app:carbon_fontPath="@string/font_regular"
                    app:carbon_textAllCaps="false" />


            </carbon.widget.LinearLayout>

            <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llTermsOfUse"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_10"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_10"
                app:carbon_rippleColor="@color/gray_normal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/terms" />

                <carbon.widget.TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                    android:text="Terms of use"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/carbon_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium"
                    app:carbon_fontPath="@string/font_regular"
                    app:carbon_textAllCaps="false" />


            </carbon.widget.LinearLayout>

            <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llPrivacy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_10"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_10"
                app:carbon_rippleColor="@color/gray_normal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/privacy" />

                <carbon.widget.TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                    android:text="Privacy Policy"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/carbon_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium"
                    app:carbon_fontPath="@string/font_regular"
                    app:carbon_textAllCaps="false" />


            </carbon.widget.LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_10"
                android:background="#99ADAFA4" />

            <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llLogOut"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size_10"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_10"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_12"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_10"
                app:carbon_rippleColor="@color/gray_normal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_30"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_logout" />

                <carbon.widget.TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_12"
                    android:text="Log out"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/carbon_black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium"
                    app:carbon_fontPath="@string/font_regular"
                    app:carbon_textAllCaps="false" />


            </carbon.widget.LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: test case make your ScrolllView **`android:fillViewport="true"`**

Comment: @NileshRathod i have already tried

Comment: share your **`XML`** layout

Comment: edited the post but i don't think its because of xml as without sliding pane its working in simple activity

Comment: than try with NestedScrollView @Aditi for test case

Comment: @NileshRathod That tried too